# How to avoid hover effect when I have mouse on specific children element

Tags: html, css

The problem is, when I hover my yellow box, the hover effect is running. How to avoid this effect when I am hover stricte yellow box.

```css
.p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.p:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: pointer-events:none on the .c element ?

Comment: As the above stackoverflow question says, its impossible with CSS but not impossible with javascript.

Comment: it is possible with just css. the pretty new pseudoclass `:has` just allows to do that easilly

Comment: Note that `:has()` is [not well supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)

Answer (score 0):

A solution w/o JS:

```css
.wrapper {position: relative}

.p {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:red;      
}

.c {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.p:hover {
  background: blue;
 }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="p"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out this is possible with CSS. However, you can also try to accomplish this with a JQuery hover effect..

```js
$(function() {
  $('.p').on('mouseover', function(e) {
      if (e.target === this) {
        $('.p').css('background', 'blue');
      }
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.p').css('background', 'red');
    });
});
```

```css
.p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:red;
  
}

.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p">
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have really simple solution for this.

just create a new class

`.noHover{ pointer-events: none; }`

and use this to disable any event on it. use it like:

`<a href='' class='btn noHover'>You cant touch ME :P</a>`

Comment: Doesn't work bud

Comment: You are still hovering on parent element, even if your pointer does nothing on that particular element